# Go to the URL when clicked on Leaflet marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers, events

I want to implement marker click event so when user click on marker it goes to url. Url is written inside an array (a[3]). However, this is my code which doesn't work, it always goes to the link of the last marker only. Can you help me? I need a function which will open a new window with url in an array of that specific marker.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var a = markers[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var link = a[3];
            var image = a[4];


         var list = 
            "<dl>"
                + "<dt>" + title + "</dt>"
                + image

                +
           "</dl>";


            var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { riseOnHover: true }).bindLabel(list).addTo(map);


            marker.on("click", function() {

                window.open(link, "_blank");

                }
            );  

        }
```

Comment: Sorry to invade your thread... but how exactly do you add a custom marker icon to this code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have written down a small piece of code might be helpful for you.

You can try working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhatabbas/qeJ78/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet - Marker Click Event</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<style>
#map {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init_map();
        add_marker();
    });
    var map;

    function init_map() {
        map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    function add_marker() {
        var points = [
            ["P1", 43.059908, -89.442229, "http://www.url_address_01.com/"],
            ["P2", 43.058618, -89.442032, "http://www.url_address_02.com/"],
            ["P3", 43.058618, -86.441726, "http://www.url_address_03.com/"]
        ];
        var marker = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            marker[i] = new L.Marker([points[i][1], points[i][2]], {
                win_url: points[i][3]
            });
            marker[i].addTo(map);
            marker[i].on('click', onClick);
        };
    }

    function onClick(e) {
        //console.log(this.options.win_url);
        window.open(this.options.win_url);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`L.marker` use a strict syntax, beware to enclose all options by `{` and separating comma.

```
new L.marker([1.25,42.3],{win_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapcamion", icon: iconPanne});
```